# Show that $\Delta \ne 0$ and LI of $G_4^3$ and $G_6^2$ are equivalent.

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

In *Complex Analysis* by Freitag it is claimed that $\Delta \ne 0$ and LI of $G_4^3$ and $G_6^2$ are equivalent; that is, if $\Delta = (60G_4)^3 - 27(140G_6)^2 \ne 0$ then $G_4^3$ and $G_6^2$ are linearly independent and conversely. But $\Delta = (60G_4)^3 - 27(140G_6)^2 \ne 0$ means that only ***one*** (up to a multiplication of $\Delta$ by a nonzero number) linear combination of $G_4^3$ and $G_6^2$ is nonzero, so how that implies that ***all*** linear combination of $G_4^3$ and $G_6^2$ is nonzero? Same question goes for the converse.

Comment: Consider the values of $G_4^3$ and $G_6^2$ at the cusp $i\infty$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, both are zero at $i\infty$, am I right? if so it can come from $\Delta = 0$ at $i\infty$. However, I can't relate this to the problem of their equivalence.

Comment: No, the point is that neither is zero at infinity, but the only linear combination that is is $\Delta$ (up to a a constant factor).